# removing value from the list

Tags: java

I have a query I have a Map like this

```
  Map ppvValidatedinfo = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

and it contains the value like this

```
   1  22 23 24 25
```

so 1 is the key(patient id) and the values(scriptinfo) are 22,23,24,25

Now I am getting this value from back end as shown below

```
String ScriptInfo = ((IItemPluRx)item).getScriptInfo();
```

> Now suppose the value of the script info is 24

I want to know whether in my Map in the values section that is in list,  does it contain 24 and if it contains then I want to remove it from list please advise how to achieve it

Answer (score 3):

```
ppvValidatedinfo.get("1").remove("24");
```

it assumes that ppvValidatedinfo is generic

```
 Map<String, List<String>> ppvValidatedinfo = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

otherwise

```
((List)ppvValidatedinfo.get("1")).remove("24");
```

note that it may throw a NullPointerException if the key is not in the map, which can be corrected 
as

```
List<String> list = ppvValidatedinfo.get(key);
if (list != null){
   list.remove(value);
}
```

Comment: there is no remove() function

Comment: Map.get("1") return List; List has remove(Object) method

Comment: so you need to write it ((List) ppvValidatedinfo.get("1")).remove("24");, because your code is gave me error

Comment: right, it assumes  Map<String, List<String>> ppvValidatedinfo = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

Answer (score 1):

You will need to iterate over the HashMap, pull out the List object, then iterate over it and if you find the search value, you remove the HashMap entry that has the corresponding key.

Comment: @Evgeniy: 
this assumes that you know that the search value is hashed at key 1