# adding one parameter additionally

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [removing value from the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474154/removing-value-from-the-list)

I have a query I have a Map like this

```
 Map ab = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

and it contains the value like this

```
  1  22 23 24 25
```

so 1 is the key and the values are 22,23,24,25

Now I want to change the structure

like this

```
 1 22 23 24 25 | M
```

as shown above that in list apart from 22,23,24,25 I want to store pipe |M also please advise how to achieve this

Comment: How did you add rest of the elements?

Comment: what do you mean by pipe |M?

Answer (score 1):

You can use just `((List<String>)ab.get("1")).add("|M")`

EDIT: Modified as it's a raw map of `<Object, Object>`. Note that this is an unchecked cast. You shouldn't be using raw types when you know what your `Map` is going to contain. The other alternative to avoid the unchecked cast is to use `instanceof` operator.

Comment: No, he can't, because `ab` is a reference to a `Map` (raw type) and not a `Map<String, List<String>>` (generic type).

Comment: Thanks, just saw the declaration.

Comment: IMHO, it's good advice to use the generic type and bad advice to introduce typecasting in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Map ab = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        ab.put("1", "22 23 24 25");
        Iterator it = ab.entrySet().iterator();

            if (ab.containsKey("1")) {
                String value = (String) ab.get("1");
                value += "| M";
                ab.put("1", value);
            }

        System.out.println(ab.get("1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

So, building on Swapnil's answer then:

```
Map<String,List<String>> ab = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

List<String> valueList = ab.get("1");
if (valueList == null) {
  valueList = new ArrayList<String>();
  ab.put("1",valueList);
}
valueList.add ("|M");
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a new list with the values and put it on map with the same key, it will get replaced.